# What is the Taylor expansion of $\arctan$ for a power series

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

My function is $x = A/t + B + C \cdot t + D \cdot t^2 + O(t^3)$.

What is the $\arctan(x)$ series expansion for small $t$?

I know the $\arctan$ expansion for small and large values, but here the first term is large, the second term is constant, and the other terms are small.

So I do not know what is the asymptotic expansion for this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: For $x > 0$, you have $\arctan x + \arctan \frac{1}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I'm sorry for my answer, I completely misread the question, disregard it

Comment: "here the first term is large, the second term is constant, and the other terms are small": so $x$ is large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=\frac At+B+Ct+Dt^2+O(t^3)=\frac At\left(1+\frac BAt+\frac CAt^2+\frac DAt^3+O(t^4)\right)$$ and

$$\frac1x=\frac tA\left(1-\frac BAt-\left(\frac{B^2}{A^2}+\frac CA\right)t^2-\cdots\right)$$ which you can plug in $\pi/2-\arctan1/x$.

Comment: thanks. So, 1/x will be small. Then I just have to expand Arctan (1/x) = (1/x) - (1/x)^3/3 + (1/x)^5/5 - ... . so that  Arctan x = pi/2 - arctan (1/x)

Comment: Or should I use McLauren series for f(x) = Arctan (x) ?

Comment: @Meva: hem, I already answered that, and from your post you also know what to do.